# INSERT INTO statement for matching row - MS Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 2 tables...

Table 1 looks like

```
ID / Name  / Amount / Number
=========================
1 / Peter / 100 /  

2 / David / 80 / 

3 / Steve /70 /
```

I would like to use 'INSERT INTO' function to fill these empty 'Number field' using Table 2 with a matching ID. [Updating existing Table 1]

```
ID / Number                          <- This is table 2
=========================
1 /  123

2 /  456

3 /  756
```

so the final table 1 should look like...

```
ID / Name  / Amount / Number
=========================
1 / Peter / 100 / 123 

2 / David / 80 / 456

3 / Steve /70 / 756
```

Any ideas? 
Is it possible to use insert into function without creating a toally new table?
Thanks

Comment: You don't need an INSERT, you need an UPDATE ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `UPDATE` query, not `INSERT`:

```
UPDATE Table1 INNER JOIN 
       Table2 ON Table1.ID=Table2.ID
SET Table1.Number=Table2.Number
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this works with the SQL dialect used in MS Access, but you could give it a try:

```
UPDATE table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.ID = table2.ID
  SET table1.Number = table2.Number
```